# Usage of だけ and しか

Tags: particle-だけ

I've been wondering about the different usages of しか and だけ.
I understand that the first one emphasizes the feelings of the speaker, negatively or positively. だけ is usually used with a positive verb (e.g. 氷菓が一つだけあります), and the inverse goes to しか (e.g. うちから学校まで10分しかかかりません).
I also know that だけ can be used with negative verbs if the sentence attributes a characteristic to something (e.g. 私たちの先生は日本人だけじゃない).

The question is, however, if I can use だけ with negative verbs even if the sentence expresses an action (e.g. 明子だけに言いませんでした/明子にだけ言いませんでした).

Comment: Yes....................

Comment: しか is only used with negative verbs so it is used for exceptions like “except” in English.

Comment: 'うちから学校まで十分しか**あ**りません', if you missed, and the answer is yea. [Other examples are](http://maggiesensei.com/2016/06/08/how-to-use-%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B-%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91-shika-dake/)  'この漢字**だけ**読めない。','玉ねぎ**だけ**食べられない。'

Comment: But isn't 「時間をたりる」right? Like in 「十分しかたりません」.